# dict.get(key, default) vs dict.get(key) or default

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, optimization

Is there any difference (performance or otherwise) between the following two statements in Python?

```
v = my_dict.get(key, some_default)
```

vs

```
v = my_dict.get(key) or some_default
```

Comment: Depends, what is `get`?

Comment: @vaultah: I am guessing they meant `dict.get(key, default)` here.

Comment: Yes.  Thanks for the edit @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is a huge difference if your value is [false-y](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

```
>>> d = {'foo': 0}
>>> d.get('foo', 'bar')
0
>>> d.get('foo') or 'bar'
'bar'
```

You should *not* use `or default` if your values can be false-y.

On top of that, using `or` adds additional bytecode; a test and jump has to be performed. Just use `dict.get()`, there is no advantage to using `or default` here.

Comment: I would add from a purely stylistic standpoint `or [default]` is not even clearer.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: if there was a performance advantage, it might have been worth the cognitive cost. But there isn't.

Comment: If you don't specify a default for `get` is the default `None`? And `None` evaluates to `False`?

Comment: @Superdooperhero: exactly.

Comment: If you want to handle missing keys differently, so when `get` returns `None`, do something else, but you *may* have keys that are *present* but also `None`, and you want to handle *those* keys as if they were also missing (because they're `None`) - THEN you will find `get(value) or ...` useful - because you deliberately want to trap falsey values from the `dict` - but you will still also be catching empty strings, zero and other falsey values of course so this only applies if that's also ok. I just wanted to spell out that sometimes this behaviour is useful.

Answer (score 11):

There is another difference: if `some_default` is not a value but an expression, it must be evaluated before being passed to `dict.get()`, whereas with `or` the expression will not be evaluated if you get a truthy value out of your dictionary.  For example:

```
v = my_dict.get(key, do_something_that_takes_a_long_time())  # function always called
v = my_dict.get(key) or do_something_that_takes_a_long_time()  # function only called if needed
```

So while it is true that it isn't safe to use `or` if your dictionary can contain falsey values, there can potentially be a performance advantage.